# HTML design - 100 % is not working for the element

Tags: html

Hii,

I am using .net 2008. When i designing the page in HTML, i have given the height of the outer table to 100%, but it is not taking to the full height of the window

Comment: how about some css/html code?

Comment: *hint: Don't use tables, use divs ;).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not so simple with 100% height.

**Why Percentage Height Fails**

> Okay, to begin, maybe I should explain
>   exactly why 100% height fails.
>   Contrary to popular opinion, it is not
>   because the browser ignores the
>   invalid HEIGHT attribute. The real
>   reason it fails is that the browser
>   does not expand the HTML and/or BODY
>   (depending on the browser) to fill the
>   browser viewport. The browser is in
>   almost all cases, in fact, rendering
>   the table as 100% high. The problem is
>   that it is 100% of the containing
>   element (HTML and BODY), which may not
>   be as high as the browser's veiwport.
>   The HTML and BODY tags represent block
>   elements that automatically expand to
>   fill the width of their container,
>   which is the browser's viewport. They
>   do not expand vertically. That can be
>   fixed.

This article will help you with your table: http://apptools.com/examples/tableheight.php

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```